# MySQL advice and investigation

Tags: mysql

Intro:
I have a Debian 8 VPS with SSD and 512MB RAM (1024MB Burst) and use it only with MySQL. I have turned off all unnecessary services and gave every resources on db and system. I have 5 workstations only. The ping and network are stable.

1. The main problem is that if I do 10 consecutive queries like this:

> ```
> (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Qtty), 0) FROM operations
> WHERE blablabla
> FROM (goods LEFT JOIN store ON goods.ID = store.GdID)
> WHERE Deleted <> -1
> GROUP BY goods.ID;
> ```

Randomly 5-6 of them are executed for 2s, but the rest for 8s or more! I see no reason for this behavior. When i activate slow_query_log, it have just the same query, nothing else.

2. My InnoDB data is 98MB is there any reason to give more RAM to innodb_buffer_pool_size or 128 is enough?
3. innodb_log_file_size must be 25% - 50%, which size would be better for me?
4. tmp dir is tmpfs, so if tmp_table_size is placed there, is there any reason to give it more RAM or is enough to use 1M for example?
5. table_open_cache - I have about 200 tables, is there any reason to make it 20000 for example, as the mysqltuner advises me?
6. Can i tuning something else?

## my.cnf

```
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
performance_schema = OFF
thread_stack = 192K
thread_cache_size = 10 #this is managed globally and is equal to max_connections
max_connections = 10
max_connect_errors = 10
connect_timeout = 20
wait_timeout = 20
interactive_timeout = 20
sql_mode = TRADITIONAL
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 250M
innodb_log_file_size = 100M
innodb_strict_mode = ON
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0
innodb_read_io_threads = 4
innodb_write_io_threads = 4
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_io_capacity_max = 3000
key_buffer = 128K
delay_key_write = ON
tmp_table_size = 10M # 32M = 53% temp
max_heap_table_size = 10M
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
table_open_cache = 5000
table_definition_cache = 3000
```

Comment: You want to run a showplan on your query. Also, you've elided the actual where clause in your question, which makes it harder to figure out what the issue might be.

Comment: @SunnyeXtreme Please post your ENTIRE TEXT report from Mysqltuner.  It will provide much information about your system, including Version of MySQL, by Engine, Data size and table counts, activity levels.  Even if it has been running less than 24 hours, much helpful information will be available.  Thread_cache_size minimum is 8 per the refman, add your 10 known expected connections for 18, please, we will go from there.  With only 512MB RAM, consider innodb_buffer_pool_size of 164M for effective size of ~128 after change setaside of 25%.

Comment: @SunnyeXtreme  Please post complete TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT …. so we can see the execution plan.  Also, is there any good reason to have interactive_timeout and wait_time at 20 seconds?  Give yourself time to take a nature break before stopping a connection, maybe 300 seconds for 5 minutes?  We really need to see the entire query to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I have a limit of characters to post here, so the results of mysqltuner, tuning primer and SELECT are here:
https://sunnyx3m.com/mysqltuner.txt
Thread_cache_size is equal to the number of connections and I can not change it, so I picked up connections to 10. For me 5 are enough (may be).
I'll make the innodb_buffer_pool_size at 164 and innodb_log_file_size at 25%.
I haven't a reason to have interactive_timeout and wait_time to 20 just advice from the Internet... I will increase it to 300.

Comment: @SunnyeXtreme  Thanks for the complete query.  Please post text results of EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT IFNULL …….. so we can see how query will be executed for analysis.  SHOW CREATE TABLE operations;  SHOW INDEX FROM operations;  SHOW CREATE TABLE goods;  SHOW INDEX FROM goods;  SHOW CREATE TABLE store;  AND SHOW INDEX FROM store;    would also be helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
max_connections=20  # from 10 to affect thread_cache_size
```

.    because 8 threads used by MySQL + 5 concurrent = 13 and you will have a few extra, please

```
tmp_table_size=16M  # from 10M   to reduce 41% temp tables created on disk
max_heap_table_size=16M  # from 10M  should always be = tmp_table_size
innodb_read_io_threads=64  # from 4 to let the ponies run
innodb_write_io_threads=64  # from 4 to push on through
```

for additional assistance, pls see my Profile, clk on Network Profile for contact info.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The wanted information is placed here: sunnyx3m.com/queries.txt

Comment: Sorry of the delaying, but i don't know how to do this "EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT". When i change the suggestions, the situation is the same. Now i trying with 80MB tmp_table_size and max_heap, and 150MB innodb_buffer_pool_size

Answer (score 0):

Again thanks for the detailed answer and sorry for the delay. Unfortunately, I travel often without internet and contact by Skype is almost impossible.

I noticed something that can help: often, when running even very small queries, the server responds with "ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away". If i repeat the operation - everything is fine. The problem is on the server, not in db?

The db is about 100MB, so i increase and max_allowed_packet to 512MB, innodb io_threads to 64. I tried with increased net_read_timeout, net_write_timeout, wait_timeout and interactive_timeout to 28800 and there is an improvement.
This is my timeouts now, does it make sense to change something?

```
connect_timeout             120
delayed_insert_timeout      300
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
interactive_timeout         28800
lock_wait_timeout           31536000
net_read_timeout            30
net_write_timeout           60
slave_net_timeout           3600
thread_pool_idle_timeout    60
wait_timeout                28800
```